# Issue with php and mysql on an insert into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

This is my code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO'".$tbl_name."'('username', 'nome', 'cognome', 'password', 'tipo')VALUES('".$submittedUsername."','".$submittedNome."','".$submittedCognome."','".$submittedPassword."','".$submittedTipo."')";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

it doesn't work and keeps telling me:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'registerusers'('username', 'nome', 'cognome', 'password', 'tipo')' at line 1

even if on line one there's just "

Comment: Thats a simple syntax error.A simple debugging can correct it.If you have any doubt check the syntax of insert query

Comment: I agree with Deepu. Also use mysqli rather than mysql

Comment: You should not be quoting table names or field names.

Comment: Next time do an `echo $sql;` in your code and execute the output in a SQL debugger. This will provide you more info and you learn from it.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: You've got to be very careful with syntax and formation of queries. Even the smallest mistakes will trigger an error. In this case, you've left out a space before the table name and got a little overzealous with your quotation marks and tics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space between your table name and your `INSERT INTO` syntax, and wrap your table names in  `. Not in single apostrophes. And remove the single apostrophes from around the table name.

**Example**

Your string currently looks like this:

```
"INSERT INTO'table'('
```

So put a space and delimit the SQL syntax from the values.

```
"INSERT INTO 'table'(
```

Then you remove the `'` from around the table name.

```
"INSERT INTO table(
```

and finally remove the `'` from around the column names.

Comment: I can't say for certain about `mysql`, but in `sql-server` (the question is tagged as both) having quotes around the table name and also the field names would absolutely make the statement fail.

Comment: Hence why I told them to remove it. I'll make it a little more clear though.

Comment: You say 'you can', when the truth is 'you must' (just tested on mysql too). Plus I mentioned field names, you must also remove quotes around those.

Answer (score 1):

You'r passing the table name as string with ' ', to pass table name you can pass without '', or using `` < this save your table name to be identified as "reserved word" so  you can call your table `status` < its work fine, but status won't work.
But your table with name nameoftablewithoutreservedword will work fine without ``

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you should have ' in your row names. Ex.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO'".$tbl_name."'(username, nome, cognome, password, tipo)VALUES('".$submittedUsername."','".$submittedNome."','".$submittedCognome."','".$submittedPassword."','".$submittedTipo."')";
```

Comment: That's not going to change anything